# seach list of strings into panda dataframe and return the entire row that contains that string to build a new csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have an large input file of as follows:

Input File:

```
1234
3546
```

And a large CSV File of millions lines as follows:

```
1234|2021-04-20  
3546|2019-05-15   
8576|2021-08-05  
4332|2018-10-04
```

I want to search the input file into the dataFrame  and I have the next code and a pseudoCode which I need to complete :

```
list_to_find    = pd.read_csv(input_file, header=None)
data_available  = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep = '|', header=None)  
values          = list_to_find.to_string(index=False, header = False)
```

list_to_find output:

```
      0
0  1234
1  3546
```

data_available output:

```
      0           1
0  1234  2021-04-20
1  3546  2019-05-15
2  8576  2021-08-05
3  4332  2018-10-04
```

pseudoCode:

```
search values into data_available
    create new_data
    new_data.to_csv('final.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

Desired csv file:

```
1234|2021-04-20  
3546|2019-05-15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to filter a dataframe based on the row values of a certain column. Pandas already has a function for this:

```py
input_file = [1234, 3546]
list_to_find = pd.DataFrame(input_file)

data_available = pd.DataFrame([[1234, 'a'],[3546, 'b'],[8576, 'c'],[4332, 'd']])

new_data = []
new_data = data_available[data_available[0].isin(list_to_find[0])] # give us data from 'data_available where data_available[0] is in list_to_find[0]
print(new_data)
```

output:

```
      0  1
0  1234  a
1  3546  b
```

Comment: Thanks so much! this solves my code.